# Java Servlet security manual authenticating a request server-side

Tags: java, security, authentication, servlets

I have a java servlet serving a website content and it is using forms authentication to login the users and let them access the content. Whenever the user access a protected resource he is redirected to a login form which is used to post the username/password to the j_security_check path in the web server. The rest is handled by the java security mechanisms which generate the user session, respond back and redirect him to the initial resource he tried to access. So far so good.

What I want to do, is provide access to the resources for non-logged in users in the following way: GET www.myserver.com/anotherLoginMethod=aasdfJKL where aasdfJK is a hash generated by the server. The server keeps an association of that has with a user account and when the user sends this GET request I need to:

1)Get the anotherLoginMethod parameter value.
2)Retrieve the associated user account ( credentials ).
3)Login the user automatically as if he was doing a POST with his username/password at j_security_check handler.

Is that possible ?

I tried using HttpServletRequest's login and authenticate methods in a Filter but with no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively simple. You need to decide
1. Where do you intend to keep the hash values and its association to the user?
2. How do you propose to give the hash to the user? Ensuring security is paramount for this step.

Once you have done this you can write a servlet filter which can intercept this request or you can have the logic in the servlet itself, get the user which is associated to the Hash value, generate a session as if the user has logged in successfully and redirect to the required URL. It is important to understand the security issues associated with such a methodology.

Comment: Sounds like a way to do it. My session though has multiple attributes that I need to set manually if I follow this way. Some of them come from filters I'm using ( Jetty's DoSFilter for example uses session to track state ). Also, does each vendor Servlet implementation handle Session attributes in a different way ? Cause I'm a bit puzzled on what attributes I have to set to the HttpSession to simulate what the Java security mechanism does.